# Simplest way to cast nullable enum to underlying nullable number

Tags: c#

Wanting to convert a nullable enum to its underlying nullable number. 
E.g.:

```
    public enum Car
    {
        Fast = 1,
        Slow = 2,
    }

    public int? CarToInt(Car? car)
    {
        if (car == null)
            return null;

        return (int)car.Value;
    }
```

Usage:

```
        Car? car = Car.Slow;

        int? num1 = CarToInt(car);  // A
        int? num2 = (int?)car;      // B
```

My question is, are methods A and B functionally equivalent? They seem to generate same results. Method B looks simpler, so seems preferred, but not sure if I have missed some edge case. Will method B work with all versions of c# which support nullable structs?

Comment: _"not sure if I have missed some edge case"_ -- like what? there's `null`...and there's not-`null`. What else could there be? Do you have a specific _problem_ you need help with? This type of open-ended question does not seem very useful to me.

Comment: nullable int =null + integer values. so if you do conversion with null check for null value and convert the non-null values to int it will yield same value by directly box into nullable int. what are you missing here? Another scenario you should check is passing null value in both methods.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: as an example, say if an earlier version of c# (from version 2.0 onwards) did not behave in an equivalent manner to current versions. It may be obvious to you, but not to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, are methods A and B functionally equivalent

The answer is yes, however they do slightly different things to achieve the same result as you can see [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE5wxApgHYCuAtmgIYBO2uWMuTiAYpQM4AuiAvIhABo6zRAGUANgHsA7r0RghjXAF9Yw5EgCWRTgH4q1ACqSAkjoAUqGvoDGNAJTqGInJoBmic3eq8+pceKOSi64IADsiP7iANxqwczhntqc9t4AdABqlOIkBLHxqvH4IAAsiACy5vaY6sxW1LY0cvVpEjL5tbjJ+qRkEM00xmacXg7ROAD0E4gAgp2uOj3kYHLm3ak040zziDsgEACc5r0Q9vkh+0e9YGc76oXKQA===)

```
public int? CarToInt(Car? car)
{
    if (car == null)
        return null;

    return (int)car.Value;
}

// Compiles to

IL_0000: ldarga.s car
IL_0002: call instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<valuetype C/Car>::get_HasValue()
IL_0007: brtrue.s IL_0013

IL_0009: ldloca.s 0
IL_000b: initobj valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>
IL_0011: ldloc.0
IL_0012: ret

IL_0013: ldarga.s car
IL_0015: call instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<valuetype C/Car>::get_Value()
IL_001a: newobj instance void valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::.ctor(!0)
IL_001f: ret

// which is equivalent to 

if (!car.HasValue)
{
    return null;
}
return (int)car.Value;
```

Apposed to

```
 int? num2 = (int?)car;   

 // Compiles to

 IL_0010: ldloc.0
 IL_0011: stloc.2
 IL_0012: ldloca.s 2
 IL_0014: call instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<valuetype C/Car>::get_HasValue()
 IL_0019: brtrue.s IL_0026

// which is equivalent to 

int? obj = car2.HasValue ? new int?((int)car2.GetValueOrDefault()) : null;
```

In summary there is no appreciable difference.

Casting looks more succinct

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are functionally equivalent, and you don't need to implement a separate function to re-cast the entity unless you know of specific edge cases in which you need to return a custom value.

Recommended reading: [Using nullable types (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types)

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
Car? car = Car.Slow;

var num2 = (int?)car;
```

Generated the following IL:

```
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldloca.s   V_0
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.2
IL_0004:  conv.i8
IL_0005:  call       instance void valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Nullable`1<valuetype HomeAccounting.Car>::.ctor(!0)
IL_000a:  ldloc.0
IL_000b:  stloc.2
IL_000c:  ldloca.s   V_2
IL_000e:  call       instance bool valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Nullable`1<valuetype HomeAccounting.Car>::get_HasValue()
IL_0013:  brtrue.s   IL_0020

IL_0015:  ldloca.s   V_3
IL_0017:  initobj    valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Nullable`1<int32>
IL_001d:  ldloc.3
IL_001e:  br.s       IL_002d

IL_0020:  ldloca.s   V_2
IL_0022:  call       instance !0 valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Nullable`1<valuetype HomeAccounting.Car>::GetValueOrDefault()
IL_0027:  conv.i4
IL_0028:  newobj     instance void valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Nullable`1<int32>::.ctor(!0)
IL_002d:  stloc.1
IL_002e:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

As you can see there  the compiler itself add call to HasValue(IL_000e) and created branches as in the CarToInt method, so the code looks equivalent.

I could think about the edge case when you cast enum to type different from the enum base type, but since we call conv instruction only if we have value it seems to be equivalent to normal casting - I mean no exception on casting Car? to int? if Car base type is long - while for boxing, e.g. this

```
double? car = 0.0;

object boxed = car;

var num2 = (short?)boxed;
```

would throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

A nice approach is to implement an extension method:

```
static class CarExtentions
{
    public static int? ToInt(this Car car)
    {
        return = (int?)car;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Car car = Car.Fast;
var intValue = car.ToInt();
```